# JQuery plugin - callback breaks other features

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to build a basic color picker plugin (mainly as an exercise to learn about plugin development).  I have a callback called "onSelected" that fires when you pick a color, but it breaks another feature of the plugin (the ability to toggle the visibility of the swatch list).

I am new to plugin development so I'm sure it's a simple mistake I'm making...

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ujg9/3/)

Plugin:

```
(function ($) {

$.colorPicker2 = function (el, options) {


    // the wrapper around the colors
    var $pickerContainer = $("<div>");


    // To avoid scope issues, use 'base' instead of 'this'
    // to reference this class from internal events and functions.
    var base = this;

    // Access to jQuery and DOM versions of element
    base.$el = $(el);
    base.el = el;

    // Add a reverse reference to the DOM object
    base.$el.data("colorPicker2", base);

    base.init = function () {
        console.log("base.init");
        base.options = $.extend({}, $.colorPicker2.defaultOptions, options);

        // Put your initialization code here
        // code goes here
        $.each(base.options.colors, function (index, value) {

            var $item = $('<div class="colorPicker-colorOption">').css({
                "background-color": "#" + value
            })

            $item.click(function () {
                console.log("item.click");

                base.selectColor(value);
            })

            $pickerContainer.append($item);
        });

        //$pickerContainer.hide();
        base.$el.append($pickerContainer);

        if (base.options.toggleElement != null) {
            base.options.toggleElement.click(function (e) {
                base.togglePicker();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        }

    };

    base.togglePicker = function()
    {
        $pickerContainer.toggle();
    }

    base.selectColor = function (color) {
        base.togglePicker();

        if (typeof base.options.onSelected == 'function') {
            base.options.onSelected.call(this, color);
        }
    }

    // Sample Function, Uncomment to use
    // base.functionName = function(paramaters){
    // 
    // };

    // Run initializer
    base.init();
};

$.colorPicker2.defaultOptions = {
    colors: [
            '000000', '993300', '333300', '000080', '333399', '333333', '800000', 'FF6600',
            '808000', '008000', '008080', '0000FF', '666699', '808080', 'FF0000', 'FF9900',
            '99CC00', '339966', '33CCCC', '3366FF', '800080', '999999', 'FF00FF', 'FFCC00',
            'FFFF00', '00FF00', '00FFFF', '00CCFF', '993366', 'C0C0C0', 'FF99CC', 'FFCC99',
            'FFFF99', 'CCFFFF', '99CCFF', 'FFFFFF'
    ],

    toggleElement: null,

    onSelected: function (color) { }

};

$.fn.colorPicker2 = function (options) {
    return this.each(function () {
        (new $.colorPicker2(this, options));
    });
};

})(jQuery);
```

How I hook into the onSelected event:

```
$(function () {
    $('#primaryColorPicker').colorPicker2({
        toggleElement: $('#selectPrimaryColor'),
        onSelected: function (color) {
            $('#selectedPrimaryColor').html("(#" + color + ")");
        }
    });

});
```

The HTML:

```
<a id="selectPrimaryColor">Toggle Color Picker</a>
<span id="selectedPrimaryColor" />
<div id="primaryColorPicker"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to learn how to write valid HTML

replace

```
<span id="selectedPrimaryColor" />
```

with

```
<span id="selectedPrimaryColor"></span>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/6ujg9/4/)

Comment: "Excellent!" (I can't believe that's what it was the entire time...good old "second set of eyes" debugging.)  Thanks.

Comment: Not easy to spot that one, but it was mysteriously overwriting some elements, and that's when I noticed you had forgotten to close the span.